# Same AP Gives One Device a Different Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I have a TL-WR720N wireless router. I was able to connect via my t460s Linux laptop before, but one day it stopped working. Now all of my devices except my laptop can connect to the same AP. Also, I'm not sure if it's a coincidence but my ISP was doing maintenance the day I started not being able to connect via my laptop.

When I connect from other devices, they connect to 10.28.16.1 and get assigned an IP like 10.28.16.* and they all work fine.

The problem laptop connects to 192.168.0.1 and gets an IP like 192.168.0.* it can only connect to the routers admin page.

Please excuse my ignorance in networking, but here are things I have tried/checked:

- My laptop will connect to other networks (like my phone's hotspot) just fine
- Resetting the router, different channels, different SSIDs
- I booted Linux mint from a thumb drive to check if there was a software/configuration issue on the laptop, but even this "fresh install" cannot connect
- I tried spoofing the MAC of my laptop to be a different one
- I checked that the BSSID that my laptop and other devices connect to are the same

Somehow, I still can't access the internet through my laptop. Nothing makes sense anymore! Would appreciate any pointers on how to debug this, or ideas on what it could possibly be.

Update: I can get my phone to connect to the "bad" network occasionally (192.168.0.1) and I can get it back on the good one by doing "renew DHCP"

Comment: What happens when you connect your laptop directly to your router using an ethernet cable? What IP address do you get? Make sure you disable wifi. Have you tried called your ISP and ask them if they changed anything to your network? Is your cable modem a router/cable modem combo?

Comment: When I connect directly it still doesn't work, and I get an IP in range `192.168.0.*`. Also, now I'm pretty certain that the issue is either with the router or the ISP as I can get my phone to sometimes get on the "bad" network on 192.168.0.1 (I can also get it back on the good network by pressing "renew DHCP" on the phone)

Comment: Is your cable modem a router/cable modem combo? What is the model number of it?

Comment: sorry, no it's not. We get an ethernet cable to the apt, not sure where it comes from.

Comment: Connect THAT cable directly into your laptop, restart your laptop. Does it give you a LAN ip address? or an actual ip address? We have to understand the source of your internet before we address anything.

Comment: OK, I will try that. Unfortunately I need to wait ~9 hours until the person sleeping in the room with that router wakes up.

Comment: This is a classic DHCP conflict. You have two devices on the network acting as a DHCP server. Are you sure you have the apartment provided network cable plugged in to the **WAN** port on your router?

Comment: I just went to the router, and the eth cable that's for the apt internet was plugged into port 2. Nothing is plugged into the WAN. When I tried putting the apt internet into WAN, none of the devices work (they all connect to 192.168.1.0). When I tried plugging that apt eth cable directly into my computer, it can't connect at all. I've read about the DHCP conflict, and that's what it sounded like to me too. The only thing is why will other devices easily connect to the right network, while my laptop *never* does even with 100s of reconnects that I've tried and manual renewals with `dhclient -r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISP and they said that they had disconnected us because they weren't getting requests from our router's MAC? It doesn't explain why some devices were still able to connect. The cable is now in the proper WAN port and all the devices are working now on the `192.168.1.*` network.

The answer is not very satisfying but unfortunately I wasn't the one to call the ISP :(